# Как можно найти высоту контейнера в контейнере в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, gui, fxml

### **1 СЛУЧАЙ**

Как найти высоту контейнера anchorPane 2 или от начала Stage и до anchorPane 2 (включительно), если нам был передан в метод только ComboBox?

`/**
  * Не подходит, так как мы получаем высоту от начала Stage 
  * до anchorPane 2 (не включительно), а нам надо либо с ним, 
  * либо просто его высоту.
  */
  double y = mainParent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(2).getLayoutY();`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Решение, которые были даны для 1-ого случая.

1) А если попробовать `node.getBoundsInLocal()`? – [lampa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5030/lampa)

2) `((Region) mainParent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(2)).getHeight()`? – [Andrew Bystrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177093/andrew-bystrov)

**Оба ответа помогли решить проблему!**

---

### 2 СЛУЧАЙ

Как найти высоту контейнера anchorPane 2, если нам был передан в метод только ComboBox?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного непонятная схема. Корневой контейнер какой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти высоту контейнера в JavaFX?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769518/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-javafx)

Comment: @Сергей Березовский я вам советовал уже воспользоваться методом `getBoundsInLocal()` у объекта `Node`. Объект Node вы получаете из `getChildrenUnmodifiable()`

Comment: @alex mainParent - корневой контейнер

Comment: @lampa Что-то я не могу понять вашу мысль... `/* Здесь мы получаем высоту scrollPane, это понятно... */ double heightOfChooseAnswerCont = mainParent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(2).getBoundsInLocal().getHeight(); /* Но у меня никак не получается проникнуть вглубь scrollPane, получив его Node, я почему-то не имею возможности воспользоваться методом getChildrenUnmodifiable()*/` Может есть какой-нибудь другой метод или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @СергейБерезовский так scrollnage должен содержать внутри себя один элемент, прально? Прально, поэтому сначала находим этот элемент, а потом внутри находим то, что нам нужно. `((VBox) scrollpage.getContent()).getChildren().get(2)...`

Comment: @lampa Так, прямой доступ к scollPane мы не имеет, нам только позволено плясать от comboBox! После того как я получил Node scrollPane я не могу воспользоваться методом ни getContent(), ни get Children
`ComboBox<String> comboBox = (ComboBox<String>) event.getSource(); Parent anchorPane = comboBox.getParent(); - (Контейнер в котором находится ComboBox) Parent mainParent = parent.getParent(); - (root контейнер в котором находится anchorPane в котором находится ComboBox и scrollPane) Node scrollPane = mainParent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(2)`
Далее ничего не выходит, он как будто заблокирован

Comment: @СергейБерезовский хорошо, дома гляну скину пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом выходит примерно так:

```
Parent parent = combobox.getParent().getParent(); //vbox
ScrollPane scrollPane = (ScrollPane) parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(1); // get scrollpane
VBox vboxInScrollPane = (VBox) scrollPane.getContent(); // anchor
ObservableList<Node> elements = vboxInScrollPane.getChildren(); // get elements in vbox

for(Node node : elements) { // перечисляем элементы в vbox scrollpane
    Bounds bounds = node.getLayoutBounds();

    System.out.println(node + " - " + bounds.getWidth() + " - " + bounds.getHeight());
}
```

Полный пример: https://pastebin.com/as5dBYTW

Comment: Спасибо! Только есть один вопрос. Получается метод getChildrenUnmodifiable() не дает нам в дальнейшем возможности взаимодействовать с Node, поэтому, чтобы убрать этот недостаток мы приводим наш недо-scrollPane к нормальному типу scrollPane. Но почему в дальнейшем нам также надо прописывать тип приведения у VBox, а также у children VBox, ведь scrollPane же стал полноценным Node? Правильно ли так вообще делать?)

Comment: @СергейБерезовский по сравнению с другими библиотеками я вижу тут недоработки в виде невозможности получения родителя и детей у элемента Node и приходится этот элемент приводить к определенному типу.